# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.summary' has no attribute 'image'

Tags: windows, tensorflow

I have installed Tensorflow on Windows 10 Pro in a Anaconda environment. When I try to use the tf.summary API, I systematically get AttributeError:

```
python --version
Python 3.8.12
python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2022-03-30 09:09:03.938282: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-03-30 09:09:03.939342: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\envs\tfenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\envs\tfenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.EL2C6PLE4ZYW3ECEVIV3OXXGRN2NRFM2.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\envs\tfenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
>>> print(tf.__version__)
2.8.0
>>> dir(tf.summary)
['SummaryWriter', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_sys', 'create_file_writer', 'create_noop_writer', 'experimental', 'flush', 'graph', 'record_if', 'should_record_summaries', 'trace_export', 'trace_off', 'trace_on', 'write']
>>> tf.summary.image()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.summary' has no attribute 'image'
>>> tf.summary.scalar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.summary' has no attribute 'scalar'
```

According to the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image), image and scalar are attributes of tf.summary in TF2.8. Is this error specifically related to Windows? I am using Anaconda to manage my environment, but TF was installed with PIP.

Comment: When loarding the TF library, there is a warning about a missing Tensorboard installation, while it is present in the environment. The `tensorboard` library can be imported  without error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by forcing the reinstallation of tensorboard:

```
pip install --force --no-deps tensorboard
```

It worked like perfectly after that.